# Problem with running program to print output in VS Code software

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to programming and request assistance regarding this problem. My VS code has been working fine until this morning when suddenly, it is not able to print an output in the terminal anymore when I run my code, even for simple Python commands like printing a simple message. No error message is shown and instead, I see these two lines appear in the terminal. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: without the script you try to run it is hard to tell, is the script waiting for `input()`, try the simple `print("Hello")` script

Comment: @rioV8 Oh after closing the folder and opening a new py file and trying print("Hello"), it works in printing hello

Comment: @rioV8 My mistake is so silly. Thank you for your help!